# Problema con formulario Laravel Collective

Tags: laravel-5, laravel, formularios

Resulta que estoy tratando de enviar datos, en *Laravel*, a través de un formulario utilizando *Laravel Collective*. Pero cuando apreto el botón de *Registrar* (el que inicia la petición para enviar los datos) no pasa nada. Revisando la consola, esta me muestra que el formulario se envía al método `create` del controlador y no al método `store` como debería ser. Estoy usando *Laravel 5.3* y la versión 5.2 de *Laravel Collective* (la versión PHP del servidor es *5.5*, y no me deja actualizar a la última versión del formulario). Espero que me puedan ayudar.

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('title' ,'Agregar Evento')

@section('content')

<div class="container">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"> <h3 class="panel-title"> Nuevo Evento </h3>  </div>

    <div class="panel-body">


{!! Form::open(['route' => 'agenda.store' , 'id' => 'formAgregarEvento' , 'name' => 'formAgregarEvento']) !!}

  <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('name' , 'Nombre'); !!}
  {!! Form::text('name' , null, ['class' =>'form-control',  'placeholder' => 'Nombre evento' , 'required' ]); !!}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('lugar' , 'Lugar'); !!}
  {!! Form::text('lugar' , null, ['class' =>'form-control',  'placeholder' => 'Lugar del evento' , 'required' ]); !!}
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('url' , 'URL') !!}
  {!! Form::text('url' , null, ['class' =>'form-control',  'placeholder' => 'Ingrese URL' , 'required' ]); !!}
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('FechaInicio' , 'Fecha de Inicio'); !!}
  {!! Form::date('fechaInicio'); !!}
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('FechaTermino' , 'Fecha de Término'); !!}
  {!! Form::date('fechaTermino'); !!}
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('descripcion' , 'Descripción'); !!}
  {!! Form::textarea('descripcion' , null, ['class' =>'form-control',  'placeholder' => 'Descripción del evento' , 'required' ]); !!}
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button id="registrarBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Registrar </buttton>
  </div>


    {!! Form::close() !!}

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

@endsection
```

Rutas:

```
Route::get('/admin/agenda', 'EventoController@index'); // un evento se considera una agenda 
Route::resource('agenda', 'EventoController'); 
Route::resource('informaciones', 'InformacionesController');
```

[image: Rutas mediante artisan]

Controlador

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\Evento;
use DB;


class EventoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
     public function index(){

            $eventos = \App\Models\Evento::all();

            return view('agenda.index', ['eventos' => $eventos])->render();


    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {

            return view('agenda.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // 
        $evento = new \App\Models\Evento($request->all());
        $evento->save();

    }
```

EDIT: Finalmente no seguí utilizando el formulario de *Laravel Collective*. Agregue los inputs y el formulario de la forma "clásica". Además hice una llamada Ajax ,mediante jQuery, para acceder al controlador y así insertar los datos. Dejo los código

jQuery:

```
   $("#registrarBtn").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
      var dataForm = $("#formAgregarEvento").serialize();
      $.post('/agenda' , dataForm , function(e){
          alert('Evento Agregado');


      });
```

Controlador Store:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // 
   DB::table('eventos')->insert([

       'titulo' => $request->input('titulo'),
        'descripcion' => $request->input('descripcion'),
        'lugar' => $request->input('lugar'),
        'url' => $request->input('url'),
        'fechaInicio' => $request->input('fechaInicio'),
        'fechaTermino' => $request->input('fechaTermino')

    ]);

     return view('agenda.create');


}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos el archivo de rutas?

Comment: Lo agregué al post principal

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer desde la consola: `php artisan route:list` y agregar el resultado a la pregunta?

Comment: Agregado , ademas agregue una solucion que encontré

Comment: Según tu problema el formulario se envía a `/agenda/create` y no a `/agenda`? La solución que encontraste, aunque funciona no sigue mucho los estándares de Laravel.

Comment: Claro , enviaba a _/agenda/create_ y no a _/agenda_  aun cuando yo especificaba la ruta o el controlador.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba enviado la acción en vez del route, el método por defecto siempre es POST

```
Form::open(['action' => 'EventoController@store'])
```

Comment: No funcionó, aun no me captura los datos. Hice una petición en ajax a travès de jQuery, pero aun asi no me capturan los datos. Lo que si hace es guardarlos en la base de datos , pero lo guarda como registros vacíos . Agregué el controlador por si algo ayuda.